# "Перекрестье" vs. "перекрестие" — what's the difference?

Tags: выбор-слова

Are "*перекрестье*" and "*перекрестие*" two different words with different meanings? Or are they two variants of the same word? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: They have different meanings.

Comment: @V.V. Do you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 4):

> перекре́стие, -я (в оптике)

Refers to optics, such as cross hairs in a gun optical scope

> перекре́стье, -я, р. мн. -тий

Refers to an intersection of something or something that forms a cross.

src: http://orfo.ruslang.ru/search/word

src: https://www.efremova.info/word/perekrestje.html#.Wei6iIZrxYg

Comment: I think this answer is almost correct. Having analysed the examples from the national corpus you can clearly see that the form "перекрестие" appears only in connection with optics, but we should mention that both forms are equally used in this meaning.

Comment: Colloquial "перекрестье "(см.shabunc's answer) appeared only in the 20th century and has two corresponding non-colloquial pairs "перекресток"(дорог) and "перекрещение"(судеб, линий).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I couldn't locate the historical aspect. :)

Answer (score 4):

They have exactly the same meaning. In written Russian, nouns ending in *'-вие'*, *'-тие'* or *'-лие'* are often changed to use *'-ье'* instead for a poetic, sublime, or 'old-fashioned' effect: *призванье*, *долголетье*, *страданье*, *тренье*, *понятье*, *бесправье*. - however, you won't encounter those in nowadays speech very often.

A reverse substitution can sometimes be observed in some nouns ending in *'-ье'*: *похмелие*, *веселие*, *бездорожие*, although one will typically find such usage only in pre-20th-century written sources or in texts mimicking those.

Comment: в принципе согласен, но есть и исключения: никогда не слышал "Приветствье". Это про *In written Russian, nouns ending in '-вие'*

Comment: Согласен, исправил.

Comment: It's fine as a general idea for the majority of words, but every rule has its exceptions, so it doesn't asnswer the question at all.

Answer (score 4):

Words ending with '-ие' such `перекрестие`, `мерцание`, `создвездие` and so on quite often have alternative form ending with `-ье`, like in `перекрестье`, `мерцанье`, `созвездье`.

**Generally speaking, `-ье` form is either poetic, obsolete and/or used in colloquial speech.**

The answer provided is strictly speaking wrong. Let's refer to the [link](https://www.efremova.info/word/perekrestje.html#.Wei7bhOCxp9) provided:

> перекре́стье
>   **ср. разг.** Место пересечения чего-л. То, что имеет форму креста.

So, this is just a colloquial form. 
The other thing is that for some words there's indeed a tendency to designate different things - like `воскресенье` for Sunday and `воскресение` for the Resurrection.

May be we are facing the same kind of process with `перекрестье` and `перекрестие` but I'd rather say they **these words are interchangeable but `перекрестие` is preferable**.

Comment: What about "перепутье"? Is "перепутие" preferable?

Comment: @enkryptor well, not every possible pair exists, so the only valid word would be "перепутье" (the same about "распутье")